# Typescript: Infer property type from another property type of a class

Tags: typescript

I want infer a type from another class property type.

- if `foo` property is string `'x'` the bar property type is interface `X`
- if `foo` property is string `'y'` the bar property type is interface `Y`
- if `foo` property is string `'z'` the bar property type is interface `Z`

the goal is

```
if( this.foo === 'z') {
    // this should be an error for ts, because id foo is 'z', bar is Z { z: boolean }
    this.bar = {y: value};
}
```

this is my approach

```
interface X { x: boolean }
interface Y { y: boolean }
interface Z { z: boolean }

type InferResult<T> = T extends 'x' ? X : 
                      T extends 'y' ? Y : 
                      T extends 'z' ? Z : Z; // default Z


class MyClass {
      private foo: 'x' | 'y' | 'z' = "x";
      private bar!: InferResult<MyClass["foo"]>; // expected X because foo is X but bar is X | Y | Z

      constructor(foo: 'x' | 'y' | 'z'){
        this.foo = foo;
      }

      setBar(value: boolean){
        if( this.foo === 'x') {
           this.bar = {x: value};
        } else if( this.foo === 'y') {
           this.bar = {y: value};
        } else if( this.foo === 'z') {
           // this should be an error for ts, because id foo is 'z' bar is Z { z: boolean }
           this.bar = {y: value};
        }
        console.log(this.bar, this.foo)
      }
}
```

[PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAAjISwOwFwUwE4DMCGBjOIAaIDeIAPALhACMB7cgGzhShAF9Rxp5l1MBNPEATxIrVa9JuEixEqDCABaPAF4DKNOo2Zh1IGLwAOmAJJQkiAEpwAzgFcqMADwAVAHwgAvCHsg4BeFAAm5kAByAkCQAH5sEBJNMVi4%20I8vH38g3lCI7mj47JywRO84PwDA%20XTZKNkAbhAAehqQXzhUaxhZTXaxNCoUcwCAWV4AYW7evBjYnQQIADcUeBAkShJg0IAfVLWg0tcQACICXcrxsUmZucxSFAQAQhJDYwQzKxtbAeGe8wBtXcXyXYBdRzVOqeAh6NDwXyRUhwNAoSzmTC-SABHCkSytS4IFGRdbcdYyDo5NDkKDmGAISwQ8gIAAUv2WIRA60CaWZW0CAEpcMdYjAABYQcwAOmRbl%20R1yonAvLAiJgACErrTZlRLHAlEI6NzZSwkLStIKRWKXG4Vpyxrk%20UbhVidrhiCBVeqGJKrQxPFREZB9YahaLKK5TRsLTyrWIBf67W5cPwnSg1XBXbqwB64F7MBBfZHjYHTWbSqGUxGbdG8Ip44nk%20HpbkSWShMKqOQAOa0nO2q4AGj9ufInN1tbUQA)

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for `bar` to be `X` because `foo` is of *type* `'x' | 'y' | 'z'` and not just of type `'x'`; it's not readonly and control flow analysis to work doesn't work across method boundaries anyway.  You really want `MyClass` to be a discriminated union, but this is not possible in TypeScript, classes can't be unions; you can push `foo`/`bar` down into a subproperty and make that a union, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WG2g0m).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ok, thanks, your idea works!